# Add http headers to RestTemplate by Interceptor or HttpEntity?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-web

If I have some static headers that should be applied to *any* request sending with `RestTemplate`: how should those be added?

In this example, I'd always want to sent the http header `accept=applicaton/json`. (it could as well be any other header, also multiple ones).

1) `HttpEntity` directly before sending:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

ResponseEntity<Rsp> http = restTemplate.postForEntity(host, new HttpEntity<>(req, headers), type);
```

2) `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`:

```
class MyInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}

@Bean
public RestTemplateCustomizer customizer() {
    return restTemplate -> restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
}
```

And then just post:

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(host, req, type);
```

Which one has an advantage over the other, and should thus be preferred?

Comment: Interceptors are generally used for inbound requests, for the outbound request you can just have a utility method that does that for you.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Could you give an example? Because, as seen above by `HttpRequest request`, so I don't think its purpose is for inbound requests.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. I did not know about it. There seems to be an interceptor for client requests. I would say the Interceptor is a better way of doing it is all the requests really need similar addition to requests.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 seems a little hard to maintain since the developer would need to remember to do it every time. Option 2 would be better, I would only do the following change:

Where you do

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor())
```

I would do

```
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
    interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
}
interceptors.add(new MyInterceptor());
restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

This way you can initialize the list in case it's empty.

Also, be careful because someone can set a new interceptor list to the bean and lose yours.

Comment: The Interceptor list is initialized by default with empty ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 Lambda way of doing it with interceptor

```
new RestTemplateBuilder().interceptors(
   (HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) -> {
      request.getHeaders().set(AUTHORIZATION, token);
      return execution.execute(request, body);
   }
).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `HttpEntity` directly before sending: fine-grained control of the restTemplate. It works but you must repeat the code everywhere and the developer may forget it (DRY)

2) `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` with `RestTemplateCustomizer`: Each restTemplate created from restTemplateBuilder bean will have this interceptor, suitable for a general behavior.

Comment: Do you know if the developer may additionally override the headers that have been set by `RestTemplateCustomizer`, by using the `HttpEntity`? Or does it work the other way around: interceptor overrides HttpEntity headers?